# Docker using less memory than allowed amount specified in GUI

Tags: docker, containers, docker-machine

I am using a docker linux container on a windows 10 machine. I have the following options specified in advanced tab of docker gui:
[image: GUI]

and yet my docker container is just using 14GiB of memory. 
[image: docker stats output]
I want to be able to use all the memory in docker i can after leaving a safe amount for windows processes. I wont be using the ram for anything other than in docker and what windows will use to run.